# In the Mortal Kombat series, what is the origin of the "toasty" guy?

Tags: mortal-kombat-series

What is the origin of this, is there a background story?

From Mortal Kombat 2 there has been a guy that on chance pops out of the bottom right hand screen saying "toasty" whenever scoring a good upper cut.

Note: I realise that the toasty chance in the older MK games were to fight special hidden characters. I'm looking for how the toasty guy came about to be in the game and why he says "toasty". +1 to anyone that includes visuals in their answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "Toasty" guy is Dan Forden, he's a sound programmer and composer who worked, among other things, on the Mortal Kombat series

You can read more about him on [this WikiPedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Forden)

Comment: Neat. I didn't realize this was a MK meme, I've seen it on some random youtube videos though.

Comment: BTW, the guy laughing at the end of the video is Ed Boon, creator of Mortal Kombat and half the origin for Noob Saibot's name, the other half is John Tobias

Comment: This video explains it better http://youtu.be/pRFMgHBNA5Y